Gas water heater: power connection to a thermostat
I purchased a Netatmo smart thermostat, which is supposed to be compatible with my Saunier Duval Thema NOx F25 domestic gas water heater. According to the heater's manual, a connector labeled X16 should provide 230 V power for the thermostat. However, upon inspection, I found that the X16 connector is not present. Instead, there is a male edge connector on the circuit board where a female connector might fit.
My questions:

Can I purchase a compatible connector to enable the 230 V connection?
If not, what alternatives are there to obtain 230 V power without cutting or splicing cables directly on the heater?

Your advice would be greatly appreciated.


That needs a card edge plug. Specifically, a RAST 2.5 plug with a 5 mm pitch (my site). You can buy RAST 2.5 plugs with 4 circuits and a 5 mm pitch here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2-1740533-4/4898332
